# How to scroll UITableViewCell to specific position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView`, each `UITableViewCell` has a `UITextField`. When a `UITextField` is selected I animate the `UITableView` onto the screen then I change the `UITableView` size so that the user can see the `UITableViewCell` that the `UITextField` is in.

Currently everything works and the `UITableViewCell` is shown at the very bottom, the problem being when the user hit the enter key I try to set the next `UITableViewCell` `UITextField` as the first responder then scroll it into view.... however the problem is is that this next field is not yet loaded so I am having trouble accessing this.

I would like to know if there is a way to initally scroll the first selected UITableViewCell / `UITextField 2 or 3 up from the bottom so when enter is hit there is no worry about the next`UITextField`not being loaded.... currently I have tried writing an off set but it dosnt work if I select a`UITextField` that is in the bottom half of the screen... this is what the code looks like.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:self.finishingTableView];
CGPoint pt = rc.origin;
pt.x = 0;
if(rc.origin.y > 200)
    pt.y -=  150;
else
    pt.y -= rc.origin.y;
    [self.finishingTableView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
```

Comment: Can you accomplish what you want using `[UITableView -scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has a method for that:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can play around with `scrollPosition` to achieve a desired result.

Comment: With regards to this method can I call it only when the keyboard is showing as there is no problem with my current code when the keyboard is not showing.

Comment: The only issue I have with scrollToRowAtIndexPath is that it moves the selected UITableViewCell to middle or top first time which is fine... but then if the user selects something thats not the last cell it gives me undesiered results...

Comment: I have also just tested using UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle and if I select something in the bottom half of the UITableView it causes the same problem, where it dose not scroll to middle position and when you hit enter it looses UITextField Focus.